# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp{(ax)}-\exp{(bx)}+(b-a)x}{1-\cos{(x)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp{(ax)}-\exp{(bx)}+(b-a)x}{1-\cos{(x)}}$

using L'Hopital's Rule (and not Taylor).

---

As one said, using Taylor would probably make this problem easy, but the problem lies in fact that I cannot use taylor. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: For a change, and after the semi fiasco of your previous, very recent, question, would you specify the tools you *are* allowed to use? And you definitely should explain what happened when you applied L'H to this limit. Because you did try something before posting, right?

Comment: What are your ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using L'Hopital's rule twice works well:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}+(b-a)x}{1-\cos(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ae^{ax}-be^{bx}+(b-a)}{\sin(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^2 e^{ax}-b^2 e^{bx}}{\cos(x)}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Results in $a^2-b^2$ I guess?

Comment: @TylerDur Yes, that's right.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I get the feeling these are just homework questions, since the OP clearly knows the definition of L'hopital's rule

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{ax}-e^{bx}+(b-a)x=e^{ax}-ax-1-(e^{bx}-bx-1)$$

Now, using L'Hospital $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{cx}-cx-1}{1-\cos x}=c\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{cx}-1}{\sin x}=c^2\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{cx}}{\cos x}=c^2$$

Alternatively use  Taylor's expansion, $e^{cx}=1+cx+\dfrac{(cx)^2}{2!}+\cdots$

Comment: See this(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) the proof without  L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion